# C# Split time List into time ranges

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

I am looking to extract ranges from an list of integers using linq:

for example I am looking to split the following list:

```
List<int> numberList = new List<int>() { 30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180, 270, 300, 330 };
```

into a list of integer ranges that will look like:

```
{ 30, 180 }
{ 270, 330 }
```

ie: where the next seq is greater than 30

another example :

```
List<int> numberList = new List<int>() { 30, 60, 120, 150, 270, 300, 330 };
```

into a list of integer ranges that will look like:

```
{ 30, 60 }
{ 120, 150 }
{ 270, 330 }
```

I have tried with for loops to find the best way possible however I don't
know where to start trying to use a linq query to do this.

Comment: Can you state more clearly how you are choosing the sequences to be extracted?

Comment: He means that a new range starts wherever an element is more than 30 larger than the previous element.

Comment: Do you care whether you do this via a for loop or linq? What would you put for the range given {30, 100, 200}? Would it be {30, 30}, {100, 100} etc?

Comment: sorry if I wasn't specific enough it is exactly as @hatchet says - wherever an element is greater than 30 then that marks the end of a range and the start of the next one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a method to handle the split:

```
IEnumerable<IList<int>> SplitValues(IList<int> input, int difference = 30)
{
    List<int> results = new List<int>();
    int last = input.First();
    foreach(var value in input)
    {
        if (value - last > difference)
        {
            yield return new[] {results.First(), results.Last()};
            results = new List<int>();
        }

        results.Add(value);
        last = value;
    }

    yield return new[] {results.First(), results.Last()};
}
```

This matches your specifications as described, returning:

```
{ 30, 60 }
{ 120, 150 }
{ 270, 330 }
```

Note that a single value within the collection without a range will be duplicated. For example, `{ 30, 120, 150 }` will return:

```
{ 30, 30 }
{ 120, 150 }
```

Comment: Wow - this works for me - I especially like the addition of the difference param!

Comment: Sorry - first time using stackoverflow - Is the etiquette to wait 24 hours before accepting an answer?

Comment: @Wattcey No - but I (personally) like to give people 20-30 minutes to at least get an answer in first.

Comment: Thanks I'll allow more time in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in one linq statement:

```
var numberList = new List<int>() { 30, 60, 120, 150, 270, 300, 330 };
var section = 0;
var result = numberList
            .Select( (x, i) => new {value = x, section = (i == 0 ? 0 : ((x - numberList[i - 1]) > 30 ? ++section : section))})
            .GroupBy(x => x.section)
            .Select(x => x.Select(v => v.value).ToList()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Well. There are many ways to do so and all have their pros and cons.
So here's yet another solution, hope it will be helpful to someone.

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource[]> ToRanges<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TSource, TSource, bool> isNear)
{            
    List<TSource[]> result = source./*OrderBy(value => value).*/Aggregate(
        new List<TSource[]> { new[] { source.First(), source.First() } },
        (ranges, currentValue) => {
            TSource[] currentRange = ranges.Last();
            TSource previousValue = currentRange[1];

            if (isNear(currentRange[0], previousValue, currentValue))
                currentRange[1] = currentValue;
            else
                ranges.Add(new[] { currentValue, currentValue});

            return ranges;
        }
    );

    return result;
}
```

Example usage:

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>() { 30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180, 270, 300, 330 };

// split by max difference
numberList.ToRanges(
    (first, previous, current) => current - previous <= 30).ToArray();
// { 30, 180 }
// { 270, 330 }

// split by max range
numberList.ToRanges(
    (first, previous, current) => current - first <= 90).ToArray();
// { 30, 120 }
// { 150, 180 }
// { 270, 330 }
```

In addition, you can split not only integers but also, for example, words by their first letter. Or `DateTime`/`TimeSpan`. Or whatever you want.

Comment: Eloquent - I might look at using this for DateTime / Timespans as you suggest!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TakeWhile` and add the result to another list

```
void SplitByRange()
{
    List<int> numberList = new List<int>() { 30, 60, 120, 150, 270, 300, 330 }; 
    IEnumerable<int> aux = new List<int>();

    int n = numberList.First();
    int skip = 0;
    List<List<int>> output = new List<List<int>>();

    while ((aux = numberList.Skip(skip).TakeWhile(o => { bool r = (o - n) <= 30; n = o; return r; })).Count() > 0)
    {
        output.Add(aux.ToList());
        skip += aux.Count();
    }
}
```

At the end `numberList` will be empty and `output` will be a list of lists.

```
output[0]  // { 30, 60 }
...
```

The current code will required at least 1 element on the list, and if you have

```
{ 30, 100 }
```

It will return as two lists with 1 element in each

```
{ 30 }
{ 100 }
```

Comment: This works well, but it does mutate the input (so you might want to copy), and isn't super efficient (due to multiple `RemoveRange` calls)...

Comment: @ReedCopsey I changed to `Skip` instead of removing

Answer (score 0):

You must use LINQ? If not, what about:

```
List<int> numberList = new List<int>() { 30, 60, 120, 150, 270, 300, 330 };  

Dictionary<int, int> result = new Dictionary<int, int>();
int lastStart = numberList.First();
for(int i=1; i < numberList.Count; i++)
{
    if(numberList[i] >= lastStart + 30)
    {
        result.Add(lastStart, numberList[i]);
        if (i == numberList.Count - 1) break;
        lastStart = numberList[i + 1];
        i++;
    }
}

foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{{{0}, {1}}}", item.Key, item.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private static List<int[]> GetGroups(List<int> numberList)
{
    List<List<int>> groups = new List<List<int>>();
    numberList.Zip(numberList.Skip(1), (a, b) =>
    {
        if ((b - a) == 30)
        {
            if (groups.Count == 0)
                groups.Add(new List<int>());
            groups[groups.Count - 1].Add(a);
        }
        else if (a == b)
        {
            groups[groups.Count - 1].Add(a);
        }
        else
        {
            groups[groups.Count - 1].Add(a);
            groups.Add(new List<int>());
        }
        return a;
    }).ToList();
    groups[groups.Count - 1].Add(numberList.Last());
    return groups.Select(g => new[] { g.First(), g.Last() }).ToList();
}
```

Sample usage:

```
//List<int> numberList = new List<int>() { 30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180, 270, 300, 330 };
List<int> numberList = new List<int>() { 30, 60, 120, 150, 270, 300, 330 };
var result = GetGroups(numberList);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    int bin = 15;
    
    var start = DateTime.Parse("08:00:00");
    var end = DateTime.Parse("09:00:00");
    
var timeFrame = Enumerable
    .Range(0, Convert.ToInt32((end.TimeOfDay.TotalMinutes - start.TimeOfDay.TotalMinutes) / bin))
    .Select((s,i) => start.AddMinutes(i * bin)).ToList();
    
    foreach (var t in timeFrame)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"T: {t}");
    }
```